# Sencha Touch tutorials or examples for RSS Feeds in html5

Tags: rss, sencha-touch

I am a newbie in building Sencha Touch with html5. I would like to have some good examples of Sencha Touch for Building news RSS or tutorials

1. Splash screen
2. home page with the list of news RSS with the possibility of the upadate with the option pull to refresh

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)
It is good if you can tell us whatever you have tried or Read or Experimented before asking such questions.

If you want to look at splash image generate a blank sencha app, open it in browser and notice how startup screen is shown and what code is required.

If you want to read RSS feeds using sencha touch, do a google/stackoverflow search and you will get many articles/questions/examples e.g. [Sencha Touch 2: How do I display RSS feed as list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208539/sencha-touch-2-how-do-i-display-rss-feed-as-list)

Comment: Thank you for your answer , after searching i didnt find a tutorial who explain how a project mvc sencha touch 2 works , all the code i've tried doesnt work , & are based on the old version of sencha touch ..i need tutoriel to help to build my app rss respecting MVC

Comment: Check out this tutorial if you want to understand basics of Sencha touch 2 http://miamicoder.com/2012/how-to-create-a-sencha-touch-2-app-part-1/ . To read RSS you can refer to the link I have given in answer